# Using passing multple variables into a python object

Tags: python, variables, object, methods

I'm having issues understanding what I should do here. I need to create an object using a `class Runner:` and a `run()` method. The part of the code that is stumping me is this part:

```
colorA,turtleA,yourName = objA.run()
colorB,turtleB,yourName = objB.run()
```

I would love some ideas on how to get this done. I have a simple class already set up. This is what I have:

```
import turtle

class Runner:

    def __init__(self,color):
        self.color = color

    def run(self):
        self = turtle.Turtle(), "Michael Corbett"
```

Full Proj02 code:

```
from Proj02Runner import Runner
import turtle

window = turtle.Screen()
turtle.setup(300,200)

objA = Runner("red") #create one object
objB = Runner("green") #create a second object
#Call the run method on each object and unpack
# the tuple that is returned.
colorA,turtleA,yourName = objA.run()
colorB,turtleB,yourName = objB.run()

window.title(yourName)

#Manipulate the turtles to draw a picture.
turtleA.left(90)
turtleA.stamp()
turtleA.right(90)
turtleA.forward(50)
turtleA.right(30)
turtleA.color(colorA)
turtleA.forward(50)

turtleB.right(180)
turtleB.forward(50)
turtleB.left(30)
turtleB.color(colorB)
turtleB.forward(50)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make you `run` method look like this:

```
def run(self):
    return self.color, turtle.Turtle(), "Michael Corbett"
```